# Convert Multiline String (utmpdump results) into JSON

Tags: json, sed

All,

This is my first time submitting a stack overflow question, so thanks in advance for taking the time to read/consider my question. I'm currently using the 'utmpdump' utility to dump linux authentication log results each hour from a bash script, which is done using the syntax shown below:

```
dateLastHour=$(date +"%a %b %d %H:" -d '1 hour ago')

dateNow=$(date +"%a %b %d %H:")

utmpdump /var/log/wtmp* | awk "/$dateLastHour/,/$dateNow/"
```

What I'm now trying to accomplish and the subject of this question is **how can I take these results and delimited them by new line for each authentication log, before converting each authentication event into it's own JSON file** to be exported to an external syslog collector for additional analysis and long term storage?

As an example, here's some of the test results I've been using:

```
[7] [08579] [ts/0] [egecko] [pts/0       ] [10.0.2.6            ] [1.1.1.1       ] [Fri Nov 04 23:40:29 2022 EDT]
[8] [08579] [    ] [        ] [pts/0       ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Fri Nov 04 23:55:16 2022 EDT]
[2] [00000] [~~  ] [reboot  ] [~           ] [3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64] [0.0.0.0        ] [Sat Dec 03 12:28:05 2022 EST]
[5] [00811] [tty1] [        ] [tty1        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Sat Dec 03 12:28:12 2022 EST]
[6] [00811] [tty1] [LOGIN   ] [tty1        ] [                    ] [0.0.0.0        ] [Sat Dec 03 12:28:12 2022 EST]
[1] [00051] [~~  ] [runlevel] [~           ] [3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64] [0.0.0.0        ] [Sat Dec 03 12:28:58 2022 EST]
[7] [02118] [ts/0] [egecko] [pts/0       ] [1.1.1.1            ] [1.1.1.1       ] [Sat Dec 03 12:51:22 2022 EST]
```

Any assistance or pointers here is greatly appreciated!

I've been using the following SED commands to trim out unnessecary whitespace, and I know that what I probably should do is using IDF to split the results string into new lines before using brackets as the delimeter:

```
utmpResults=$(echo "$utmpResults" | sed 's/  */ /g')

IFS="\n" read -a array <<< "$utmpResults"

echo $array
```

But when I echo $array it only returns the first line...?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment here).

Comment: please add the names of the eight fields

Comment: `how can I take these results and delimited them by new line for each authentication log, before converting each authentication event into it's own JSON file` I think that's too broad for stackoverflow, it's a whole program to write. You have to parse the results line by line and using your own scheme convert them into a valid JSON formatted data. Have you considered using Python? You know, in python, you can do `import json`. Also in python, you would use https://pypi.org/project/utmp/ and forget about "trim out unnessecary whitespace" issues.

Comment: All good responses, and I appreciate the feedback! Ultimately the fields are broken down as follows (according to the utmpdump man page):

Type of record (ut_type)
PID of login process (ut_pid)
Terminal name suffix, or inittab(5) ID (ut_id)
Username (ut_user)
Device name or tty - "/dev/" (ut_line)
Hostname for remote login, or kernel version for run-level messages (ut_host)
Internet address of remote host (ut_addr_v6)
Time entry was made (ut_time or actually ut_tv.tv_sec)

@KamilCuk, I'll be more careful going forward about what I submit. But I think what jpseng has provided works!

Answer (score 2):

With the help of [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (sed for json), it's an easy task:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

jq -R -c '
  select(length > 0) |                           # remove empty lines
  [match("\\[(.*?)\\]"; "g").captures[].string   # find content within square brackets
   | sub("^\\s+";"") | sub("\\s+$";"")]          # trim content
  | {                                            # convert to json object
      "type"                 : .[0],
      "pid"                  : .[1],
      "terminal_name_suffix" : .[2],
      "user"                 : .[3],
      "tty"                  : .[4],
      "remote_hostname"      : .[5],
      "remote_host"          : .[6],
      "datetime"             : .[7],
      "timestamp"            : (.[7] | strptime("%a %b %d %T %Y %Z") | mktime)
    }' input.txt
```

**Output**

```json
{"type":"7","pid":"08579","terminal_name_suffix":"ts/0","user":"egecko","tty":"pts/0","remote_hostname":"10.0.2.6","remote_host":"1.1.1.1","datetime":"Fri Nov 04 23:40:29 2022 EDT","timestamp":1667605229}
{"type":"8","pid":"08579","terminal_name_suffix":"","user":"","tty":"pts/0","remote_hostname":"","remote_host":"0.0.0.0","datetime":"Fri Nov 04 23:55:16 2022 EDT","timestamp":1667606116}
{"type":"2","pid":"00000","terminal_name_suffix":"~~","user":"reboot","tty":"~","remote_hostname":"3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64","remote_host":"0.0.0.0","datetime":"Sat Dec 03 12:28:05 2022 EST","timestamp":1670070485}
{"type":"5","pid":"00811","terminal_name_suffix":"tty1","user":"","tty":"tty1","remote_hostname":"","remote_host":"0.0.0.0","datetime":"Sat Dec 03 12:28:12 2022 EST","timestamp":1670070492}
{"type":"6","pid":"00811","terminal_name_suffix":"tty1","user":"LOGIN","tty":"tty1","remote_hostname":"","remote_host":"0.0.0.0","datetime":"Sat Dec 03 12:28:12 2022 EST","timestamp":1670070492}
{"type":"1","pid":"00051","terminal_name_suffix":"~~","user":"runlevel","tty":"~","remote_hostname":"3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64","remote_host":"0.0.0.0","datetime":"Sat Dec 03 12:28:58 2022 EST","timestamp":1670070538}
{"type":"7","pid":"02118","terminal_name_suffix":"ts/0","user":"egecko","tty":"pts/0","remote_hostname":"1.1.1.1","remote_host":"1.1.1.1","datetime":"Sat Dec 03 12:51:22 2022 EST","timestamp":1670071882}
```

Without the option `-c` you can create formatted output.

---

To save each line in a file, you can do it like this in bash.
I have chosen the timestamp as the file name.

```bash
INPUT_AS_JSON_LINES=$(
  jq -R -c '
     select(length > 0) |                           # remove empty lines
     [match("\\[(.*?)\\]"; "g").captures[].string   # find content within square brackets
      | sub("^\\s+";"") | sub("\\s+$";"")]          # trim content
     | {                                            # convert to json object
         "type"                 : .[0],
         "pid"                  : .[1],
         "terminal_name_suffix" : .[2],
         "user"                 : .[3],
         "tty"                  : .[4],
         "remote_hostname"      : .[5],
         "remote_host"          : .[6],
         "datetime"             : .[7],
         "timestamp"            : (.[7] | strptime("%a %b %d %T %Y %Z") | mktime)
       }' input.txt
  )

while read line
do
  FILENAME="$(jq '.timestamp' <<< "$line").json"
  CONTENT=$(jq <<< "$line")   # format json
  echo "writing file '$FILENAME'"
  echo "$CONTENT" > "$FILENAME"
done <<< "$INPUT_AS_JSON_LINES"
```

**Output**

```
writing file '1667605229.json'
writing file '1667606116.json'
writing file '1670070485.json'
writing file '1670070492.json'
writing file '1670070492.json'
writing file '1670070538.json'
writing file '1670071882.json'
```

Comment: thanks so much for your response! I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer as I only created my account earlier today but if I did I certainly would!

Comment: I added code to store each line into a separate JSON file